# event.pageX/Y not working on touchmove

Tags: javascript, events, coffeescript, mousemove, touchmove

Today I had the following thing going on: I had an existing `mousemove` event and added `touchmove` later on, like this:

```
$(window).on "mousemove touchmove", (e) ->
  pos_x = e.pageX
  pos_y = e.pageY
```

Unfortunately both variables were `undefined` on mobile devices.

Comment: e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After a while I fixed it. There's a different event for touches. You can solve it like this:

```
$(window).on "mousemove touchmove", (e) ->
  touch = undefined
  if e.originalEvent.touches
    touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0]
  pos_x = e.pageX or touch.pageX
  pos_y = e.pageY or touch.pageY
```

I hope this will help others.